# android Replace callbacks with observables from RxJava2

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java2

37

Im using callback to observe asynchronous operations with Android, but I think that could be great replacing this listeners with RxJava, I also need retry 3 times when the callback call onError.

Here is my code to refactor:

```
public int search(String from, String searchContent, @NonNull Config config, QueryCallback<S=Result> callback) {

}


public interface QueryCallback<T> {
    void onError(int var1);

    void onSuccess(T var1);
}
```

the full call will as below:

```
FlowPlayControl.getInstance().search(from, 
searchContent, config, 
                            new QueryCallback<Result>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError(int i) {
                                    .....
                                }
                                
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Result result) {
                                    ......
                                });
```

I need use Rxjava to replace the callback